# Windows 10 pro 1903 boot up time - already played the SSD card

Tags: windows-10, ssd, amd-ryzen, windows-10-v1903, optane

I built a home workstation 2 years ago, including a Samsung EVO SSD (PCIe/NVME interface) and have enjoyed a snappy system and literally 6-8 second boot up times since then.

...

Until the forced update to Windows 10 Build 1903 surprised me yesterday.  Now my boot times easily exceed 60 seconds.

During this compulsory contemplation period I typically start cursing at Microsoft and the the whole forced upgrade philosophy, and the frustration of having "solved" my PC boot time once upon a time only to have it forcibly unsolved for me.  By the time I get to login I am so angry I can't remember what I was planning to do with this increasingly frustrating PC experience.   Yes, I'm in my late 40's and get off my lawn!

This bothers me, but I'm up for doing something about it besides complaining.

My system has an i7-6700K, Samsung 960 EVO, and 64GB RAM. In my understanding, upgrading any of these to the latest / greatest will only give me modest percentage improvements to where I am now, of maybe 20% or a bit more. The PCIe/NVME interfaced on an SSD was an insane upgrade at the time, but what Samsung giveth, Microsoft taketh away.

There are no order of magnitude upgrades left at this point. Ryzen CPUs have about 5X the context switching speed of the comparable Intel CPU's after all the Spectre/Meltdown mitigations, but that is narrow metric not likely to cut my boot times back down to 1/5th of what they have become.

Any Ideas?

1. A $1000 Optane based SSD might more than double the performance my     current SSD, but could even that bring my 60 second boot times back to 30 seconds or under?
2. Paper based positive affirmations taped to the monitor to reduce the frustration and put this wasted time to good use?
3. Zen meditation? / Prozac?

Comment: Besides your creative solutions, you may always rollback to version 1809 and block the update to 1903. For more advice, what is your Windows version (Home or better)?

Comment: Windows 10 pro.

Comment: 60 Second actually sounds like there is something broken to me. My system is somewhat similar to yours and there is no way I'm sat *waiting* for it to boot. Have you tried rebuilding or reinstalling? Take a backup so you can restore if that doesn't fix it...

Comment: Otherwise it might just be the first boot after the update which can be slow. Is fastboot disabled? Are you shutting down and rebooting or actually rebooting? Tell us more about your process.

Comment: It's not just the first reboot.  I've rebooted many times, after disabling a few start-up apps, it takes around 53 seconds from the BIOS logo until I get a login prompt.  Some of that is BIOS as it takes 10-12 seconds before the windows logo and toilet swirl shows up.  But even from there it still takes 40+ seconds.  It's just frustrating compared to my Dell Laptop (7th gen i7 - so slightly newer) which literally takes 6 seconds from power-on press to login-prompt, and both run Win 10.1903 now.   I think major brand hardware configs get tested and optimized by MS, while homebrew rigs are SOL.

Answer (score 1):

Something got broken when Windows was updated.
If you have booted several times and the slow boot persists, better go back to
the previous Windows version and block the 1903 update for a few months
(or even until the next major release).

There is alternative advice that I would not recommend here, which is to do
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
I do not recommend it, since, while it might possibly fix the problem,
it will make the rollback to the previous version just impossible.

Take good backups before starting.

**To rollback to the previous Windows version**

- Enter the Settings app
- Click *Update & Security > Recovery*
- Under "Go back to the previous version of Windows 10",
  click on *Get started*
- Answer the informational question, click *Next* to advance in the questions
- When Windows will offer to check for updates, click *No, thanks*
- Enter when asked the password you used to sign in to Windows
- At the message "Thanks for trying out this build", click
  "Go back to earlier build"
- Wait for everything to finish.

**Block Windows updates**

The instructions below are for Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise and Education versions.

- Enter the Settings app
- Click *Update & Security > Advanced options*
- Note the settings that are in effect, should you wish to go back in the future
- Under "Choose when updates are installed":

  - Set the drop-down box to "Semi-Annual Channel".
    This means waiting 60 days after release.
  - Set the Feature Update deferral to 365 days.

In theory, and for as long as Microsoft honors these settings,
you have now specified to wait for the next version of Windows,
version 1903 in this case, to age for 60 days ("Semi-Annual Channel"),
and after that an additional 365 days.
Undo this when you wish to try your luck again, or when the next major update
comes along, or if a newly discovered vulnerability mandates the update.

For more information, including screenshots, and for advice for Windows 10 Home,
see the article
[How to block the Windows 10 May 2019 Update, version 1903, from installing](https://www.computerworld.com/article/3232632/how-to-block-the-windows-10-may-2019-update-version-1903-from-installing.html).